# How to send an email with Approve/Reject button options in uipath?

Tags: email, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I need to send an email indicating approve & reject buttons and take the user response back.

I'm very new to UiPath and don't have a clear idea about how to do it. Could any one please help me to solve this?

Comment: You mean sending an email to user with button in email body and recording his click response?

Comment: @manurajhada Yes, correct!

Comment: Your best bet will be to have those as links (or style links as buttons) and capture responses on the web page when a user clicks thru.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done through a designed solution with the listed steps below:

- Add buttons or link (Approve / Reject) through HTML anchor tag in the email body.
- Call a web service endpoint using anchor tag, use "href" attribute with target="_blank" to call the web service endpoint in a new tab.
- Web service request parameter can be: 1. Approval State and 2. User Email.
- Record user response in the invoked web service business logic.

Though others may have a different solution proposal to achieve the end goal.

Comment: Correct @Syfer, I would let her decide the preference b/w onClick and href.

Comment: Sorry there is no preference. When `onclick` does not work users experience will be bad. The only option is href

Comment: @manurajhada Thank you. Outlook isn't supporting for javascript as I guess. So onclick method didn't work. Href is working but i don't have clear idea about how to retrieve the response and rest of the method to be followed.

Comment: @PunyaMunasinghe you will have to create web services further to href process. :) That's altogether a different problem.

Comment: @Syfer Improved my answer, thanks. Though she is using UiPath where Robot will be performaing the operation and don't have an UX. But yes, She prefered to use Outlook which doesn't support onlick.